# Call an api from web application periodically ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Hy,
I'm trying to call api from my web application every hour and store data in my database.
This is my Code to call

```
public class GetNationFromAPI
{
    public static async Task GetNation()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PW"].ConnectionString;
            string url = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("url").ToString();//Get Url from appsettings.json
            var response = await GetApi.GetClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootDataModel>(response);
            using SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string deleteQuery = "Delete From Nation";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, con);
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            string nationtblname = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("nationtblname").ToString();//Get Table name from appsettings.json
            string nationquery = string.Format("insert into {0} (Nation_Id, Nation, Alliance_Id, Alliance, Score, VacMode, Alliance_Position, soldiers, tanks, aircraft, ships) " +
                "Values (@nation_Id, @nation, @alliance_Id, @alliance, @alliance_Position, @score, @vacMode,@v_mode_turns, @soldiers, @tanks, @aircraft, @ships)", nationtblname);
            foreach (var nations in obj.data)
            {
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(nationquery, con);
                con.Open();
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nation_Id", nations.nation_id);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nation", nations.nation);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alliance_Id", nations.alliance_id);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alliance", nations.alliance);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alliance_Position", nations.alliance_position);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", nations.score);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vacMode", nations.v_mode);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v_mode_turns", nations.v_mode_turns);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldiers", nations.soldiers);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanks", nations.tanks);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aircraft", nations.aircraft);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ships", nations.ships);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            };
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Initially I did it from console application and it worked fine however I want my web app to do automatically every hour so I tried this in startup class of web application.

```
 public class Startup
{
    private static Timer atimer;
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        atimer = new Timer
        {
            Interval = 3600000
        };
        atimer.Elapsed += await OnTimedEventAsync();
        atimer.AutoReset = true;
        atimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static async Task<ElapsedEventHandler> OnTimedEventAsync()
    {
        GetApi.InitializeClient();
        await GetNationFromAPI.GetNation();
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

When I start my application and prompted to localhost and try to view nation. I get object reference not set to an instance of object instead of blank web page.

Comment: You should look into Hangfire https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: yep.. Hangfire or some other background process (e.g AWS Lambda / Azure Function etc)